# Which tools is Best to make Accessible site ? open source or commercial?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, web-standards, screen-readers

Which tools is Best to make Web standards, W3C validate and Accessible site ? open source or commercial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Dreamweaver for its built-in accessibility support and tools.  Versions going back at least to MX 2004 have features that encourage or at least prompt for good development techniques like use of alt tags, form element labeling, data table tags (caption, summary, etc.), and so forth.  CS4 lets you configure accessibility preferences in your work environment and also offers validation for W3C and Section 508 standards.

See also:
[Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 accessibility overview](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/dreamweaver/overview.html)

Answer (score 7):

It is not about the tools; it is about what *you* do with them. I would say that any of the modern development environments give you the possibility to make sites that validates, but they also provide good opportunities for you to screw up, if you don't know what you are doing. So the best tool is *your knowledge*.

Comment: I know but i wanted to know which tool is helpful to make accessible. Dreamweaver, Eclipse, Aptana etc

Comment: Down-voting due to the fact this was a very unhelpful answer in reference to the specificity of his question.  He asked for tools, not a lecture on becoming more educated.  Education is important, yes, but what if his boss was asking him for a set of tools to test against?  If he presented his boss your answer he probably would get fired.